# Need help optimizing gspread API calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets-api, gspread

I've been toying around with gspread to push data to a Google Sheet and came up with a working script in python.

Quick background on the "job" this script has to do:

- Open Google Sheet
- Read Instagram usernames from column B
- Collect data from Instagram
- Fill in the data in column F

Now, as said, I have this working with the code underneath. But this does (at least to my understanding) uses 1 API Call per row it updates, but my sheet will have 1000+ rows with usernames, so this might end up using a lot of API calls. So I would prefer to do this in bulk. So temporarily store it and update all rows in 1 big push. From Gspread documentation I noticed that it should be possible if I can assign exact cell and column values, but I don't know how to build up my original input data to facilitate this.

My end user also occasionally inputs empty rows (god knows why..) but I noticed that my current logic fills in data here, which actually needs to go to the row below the empty one.

So I would love to get your input on how I can optimize this, and solve 2 'issues' with my current script:

- reduce the number of API calls
- properly handle empty rows

Here's my code:

```py
#import Google 
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

#Setting up connection to Google Sheet and picking up the initial values
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('file_init.json',scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open('Workbookname').sheet1
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()

ig_username_column = 2
ig_data_column = 6
ig_usernames = sheet.col_values(ig_username_column)
ig_names = []
i = 2
t = 2
for user in ig_usernames:
    ig_clean = remove_prefix(user,'@')
    ig_names.append(ig_clean)
    print(ig_names)


for name in ig_names[1:]:
    if len(name) != 0:
        print(name)
        ig_url = f'https://www.instagram.com/{name}'
        print(ig_url)
        data = instagram_metrics(ig_url)
        sheet.update_cell(i, ig_data_column, data[2])
        i += 1
    else:
        i += 1 #this is here to skip over empty rows in the Sheet
        continue

    sleep(randint(3,6))
```

Comment: You want to reduce the number of calls of ``sheet.update_cell()``. If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about ``data = instagram_metrics(ig_url)`` and the sample value of ``data``? I think that when ``data`` is put to an array and the array is put to Spreadsheet using gspread, the number of calls of Sheets API can be much reduced. For this situation, I would like to ask you about the sample value of ``data``. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: with `sheet.update_cell()` I'm updating 1 cell at a time, so practically for my test file with 500 rows, I'm doing that action 500 times. So I want to limit that, and do it in 1 big action. So instead of doing 500 * 1 write, i want to do 1 write to 500 cells (all with different data).

`instagram_metrics(ig_url)` parses the URL and retrieves basic data from IG like # of posts, username, # of followers and # of followings and returns it. So data becomes for examples: `(20, 'username', 18410, 937)`.

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the information. I thought that I could understand your question. So I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? At first, please check whether my understanding for your question is correct. If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to put the values (`data[2]` of `data = instagram_metrics(ig_url)`) from the row 2 of the column "F".
- For example, you want to put the value of `18410` of `(20, 'username', 18410, 937)` retrieved by `instagram_metrics(ig_url)` to the Spreadsheet.
- You want to put all values of "500 rows" to the Spreadsheet by one API call.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, `requests` is created in the for loop. Then, `request` is put to the Spreadsheet using the method of `update_cells()`.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
for name in ig_names[1:]:
    if len(name) != 0:
        print(name)
        ig_url = f'https://www.instagram.com/{name}'
        print(ig_url)
        data = instagram_metrics(ig_url)
        sheet.update_cell(i, ig_data_column, data[2])
        i += 1
    else:
        i += 1 #this is here to skip over empty rows in the Sheet
        continue

    sleep(randint(3,6))
```

To:

```
requests = []
for name in ig_names[1:]:
    if len(name) != 0:
        print(name)
        ig_url = f'https://www.instagram.com/{name}'
        print(ig_url)
        data = instagram_metrics(ig_url)
        requests.append(data[2])
    else:
        requests.append('')
        continue

# Select a range
cell_list = worksheet.range('F2:F' + str(len(requests) + 1))

for i, cell in enumerate(cell_list):
    cell.value = requests[i]

# Update in batch
worksheet.update_cells(cell_list)
```

#### Note:

- I think that in this modification, `sleep(randint(3,6))` might not be required.
- This modified script supposes that you have already been able to write and read values using Sheets API.

#### Reference:

- [update_cells()](https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=update_cells#gspread.models.Worksheet.update_cells)

Comment: Thanks for that! It worked ;) just had to modify `requests = []` and derivatives because it would mess with the other functions. Great solution! Thanks

Comment: @ThomasSt Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.